# jQuery - Click to hide element that I already clicked to display

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, visibility

So I've found a script that works well to display a hidden div whenever another element I choose is clicked. However, I'd like this to act more like a toggle. Can anyone help me out? I've tried tweaking the script to the best of my ability but jQuery isn't my forte.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
    document.documentElement.className += " js"; // Add js class to the HTML element
    $(function(){
      var $containers = $("#repaircontent").hide();

      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       /* Show the HTML page only after the js and css are completely loaded */
       delayShow();
      });

      function delayShow() {
        var secs = 1000;
            setTimeout('jQuery("#repaircontent").css("visibility","visible");', secs);
      }

      $('#repairtab').each(function(i,el){
        var idx = i;
        $(this).click(function(e){
          var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
          $target.not(':visible').fadeIn();
          e.preventDefault();

        })
      })
    })
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: have you though of using toggle?? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried jquery's toggle? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: How would I apply toggle in the above code? I think it might be easier to just write a new script for this one using a toggle tutorial :)

Answer (score 1):

just replace the fade in with toggle...

```
      $('#repairtab').each(function(i,el){
    var idx = i;
    $(this).click(function(e){
      var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
      $target.toggle();
      e.preventDefault();

    })
  })
})
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Simple enough, my jquery syntax is lacking. Thanks for the quick help. This did the trick.